# Cannot read set userdata session from another controller

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have MY_Controller Extends CI_Controller

I have A Controller Extends MY_Controller and B Controller Extends MY_Controller

When I set session set_userdata in MY_COntroller  in can be access in A Controller and also B Controller

But when set session  set_userdata in A_Controller  it can't be access in MY_Controller and B Controller
But after set session in a controller and print all userdata,  the session is exist but not exist in other controller (B & MY COntroller)

IVE set the autoload libraries and also the config

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 1800;
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;


My COntroller extends CI CONtroller

 function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->readPath();
        $this->readApiConfig();
$this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('user_agent');
}

Login Controller extends My Controller

function __Construct()
    {
        parent::__Construct();
        $this->load->library('encrypt');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('captcha');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('cookie');
        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
    }



function login(){
   $email = array(
                'usr_email' => $this->input->post("email")
            );

   $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $email);
   redirect('landing');
}


Landing Controller extends My COntroller
function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('encrypt');
    $this->load->library('session');
    }
        function index() {
            //$prod = $this->getExistingAccount();
            print_r($this->session->userdata('logged_in'));die();
}
```

AND ALSO I TRY to ses   sess_save_path to APPPATH."CI_SESSION";

and add folder inside application folder name CI_SESSION and set the permission to 0700   but show white blank page

Web url : 192.xxx.x.x : port

Comment: You need to share your controller code. We might be able to help you.

Comment: @mail2bapi updated